# As a new Rails developer, is it better to jump in the deep end with a large project or start small?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

So I have a project - which I guess can be considered a relatively 'large-ish' project, that I want to build.

However, I am completely new to Rails. I am intimately familiar with UX & front-end development, but dealing with the back-end is new to me. I really want to learn though, and I remember DHH famously saying that the best way to learn is just to do it.

However, I was recently speaking to an experienced Rails developer and he said it might be better to build smaller projects - so I can learn in shorter durations and not get discouraged. Then I spoke to another experienced Rails developer and he said that there is something to be said about jumping in the deep end.

So what do you guys think? What are the pros and cons of both?

Comment: User Experience. Usually is used interchangeably with UI - User Interface design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jumping in at the deep end is fine if you know enough to plan your project carefully. If you don't know anything about MVC architecture, you will probably have a really hard time planning out the database and program elements you need to get from point A to Z.

Properly planned, you can do a project by creating successive (fully functional) iterations with each one a step toward completely fulfilling your requirements. For example, with a blog you could first build a system for entering posts into your DB, then build a display function, then build tagging, then build commenting, etc.

If you don't know anything about Rails and don't know MVC, then at least a couple of tutorial level projects will be real helpful for getting you familiar with the environment and the architecture concept.

Comment: That's what I figured. I have done the Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl, and built that Twitter clone with him. I am also getting some guidance with the models needed for my project. So I figure I can break it down like that - like you said. It's just the learning everything at once, that is a bit overwhelming - i.e. Ruby, Rails, TDD, RSpec syntax, server administration, db design, etc.

Comment: +1 for agile techniques.

Comment: marcamillion: Just be aware that you WILL make mistakes that cost you a lot of time, and that you will probably NOT do things the most efficient way every time (I've been killed a few times by building a huge piece of code to do something easily handled by a function I was ignorant of). Be patient, and stick to your plan. If you find the plan won't work, make another. Don't just wing it from there.

Comment: @bikerboy you are absolutely dead-on. I guess I kinda want it to be perfect, so I would rather 'write crappy code' on smaller projects than do the same for my larger project. But maybe I should just jump in, learn and then if anything - do a major re-write later once I have learned a bunch of new stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly it's a different answer for everyone. Which do you think would benefit you most? If you think you would be too overwhelmed by a large project then start small and continue when you feel comfortable.

What would I do? I'd jump straight in. No matter which you choose to do your larger project is likely to contain more tasks, issues, and ultimately a lot of troubleshooting. That's a good thing, though.

The nice thing about using Rails is that it's fairly easy to build all of your models and database elements with all of its generators. Then you can simply copy any view or controller logic you've already implemented.

Comment: This is exactly my sentiment. As a matter of fact, I have done that already...quickly generated some of my models, controllers and stuff. It's just the filling in everything else and getting it all to play together that can seem a bit daunting...but I guess one step at a time - as you said.

Answer (score 2):

Some time ago, a smart developer told me to avoid "analysis paralysis" and to start designing my solution as soon as I could. In my experience I've learned that every large project could be divided in smaller ones. Rails, and all the frameworks built like it, are good on both concept:
- it helps you in designing a solution by dividing Data, Business Logic and Presentation.
- it helps you in passing from idea to code
- it has some convention that could shorten your learning curve
- it's good for DRY coding

So since you already have a project go with it. If you can find another crazy developer that is willing to help you, you'll discover that rails is good also for teams and at the same time you'll learn how nice is to work together, share ideas and discuss.

So... Time to go, type at your prompt:

```
rails new my-largish-cool-project
```